# React verstion control on VScode between windowns and mac

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

Good day,

I started to learn React, called react-complete-guide. I work on two laptops windows and mac. I installed Node.js on both laptops. I started the project on mac and set it up without any issues. After finishing I ran gid add, commit and push to Github.
Thereafter, I wanted to clone the project to a windows computer.
I created a folder,
I clone the project from Github to this folder.
i m in CL
C:\Users\Alexey\Documents\Coding\React\react-complete-guide>
I ran npm install - got response all up to date.
then npm start and got the following error:

```
npm ERR! missing script: start
```

please help to solve this problem. thank you.

Comment: Did you remember to `cd` to the folder after cloning?

Comment: Yes. I did cd but after it remained in the same folder as the project, as shown in my question. Which  folder I have to cd to?